# How to read the nested table <td> values using VBA?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

Anyone help me here by saying that how to read the nested html table  values from a third party application using Excel VBA? as an example below i pasted a part of the HTML source where i want to read the all the  value and want to store it into the excel.But in here all are nested tables they used,and the tables don't have any name also in the html source i have seen.

```
<td>
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="data">
<tr class="colhead">
<th colspan="3">Expression</th>
 </tr>
<tr class="colhead">
<th>Field</th>
<th>Operator</th>
<th>Answer</th>
</tr>
<tr class="rowLight">
<td width="40%">        
Location Attributes:  LOC - Sub Commodity
</td>
<td width="20%">
= 
</td>
<td width="40%">
Abrasives
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowDark">
<td width="40%">
Location Attributes:  LOC - Commodity Tier1
</td>
<td width="20%">
= 
</td>
<td width="40%">
Advertising, Sales &amp; Promotion
</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks,
Arup

Comment: How is this a nested table? There isn't even a table declaration.

Comment: i took the part of the source html.. Do you want me to paste here the full source code? tell me then i will do that..

Comment: I have updated the source html. This what the HTMl source i got from the web page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I read an HTML table:

```
Sub ReadHTMLtable()
Dim htmldb As New ADODB.Connection
Dim htmlcmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

With htmldb
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=Z:\filename.html;Extended Properties=""HTML Import;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
    .Open
End With

Set htmlcmd.ActiveConnection = htmldb
htmlcmd.CommandType = adCmdText
htmlcmd.CommandText = "Select * from [table]"
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open htmlcmd

'process rs here

End Sub
```

this uses ADO, but it should be the same for DAO

Comment: But for that i need to save the the webpage as .html in the local machine,but how to do that at runtime?

Comment: what are the references i need to include for this in the MS Excel?

Comment: Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: I want only the values to be saved in seperate excel with the column names Field name,Operator and values.for eg. here Field name->Location Attributes:  LOC - Sub Commodity,Operator->=,answer->Abrasives and Field name->Location Attributes:  LOC - Commodity Tier1,Operator->=,answer->Advertising, Sales &amp; Promotion. So how to do that. I am only interested to these kind values to get the from the webpage to excel as a dump.

Comment: Can you help me here by suggesting some good way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4):

please find the code below :

```
Option Explicit 

Sub TableExample() 
    Dim IE As Object 
    Dim doc As Object 
    Dim strURL As String 

    strURL = "[URL="http://example.comwww.dectech.org/football/index.php"]http://example.com[/URL]" ' replace with URL of your choice

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    With IE 
         '.Visible = True

        .navigate strURL 
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop 
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop 
                Set doc = IE.Document 
                GetAllTables doc 

                .Quit 
            End With 
        End Sub 

        Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object) 

             ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

            Dim ws As Worksheet 
            Dim rng As Range 
            Dim tbl As Object 
            Dim rw As Object 
            Dim cl As Object 
            Dim tabno As Long 
            Dim nextrow As Long 
            Dim I As Long 

            Set ws = Worksheets.Add 

            For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE") 
                tabno = tabno + 1 
                nextrow = nextrow + 1 
                Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow) 
                rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno 
                For Each rw In tbl.Rows 
                    For Each cl In rw.Cells 
                        rng.Value = cl.outerText 
                        Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1) 
                        I = I + 1 
                    Next cl 
                    nextrow = nextrow + 1 
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I) 
                    I = 0 
                Next rw 
            Next tbl 

            ws.Cells.ClearFormats 

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires references to be set to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft Internet Controls`

```
Sub Extract_TD_text()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
    Dim r As Long

    'Saved from www vbaexpress com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=17
    URL = "your file pathe/URL"

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True

        'Wait for page to load
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLdoc = .document
    End With

    Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("TD")

    Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents

    r = 1
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        'Look for required TD elements - this check is specific to VBA Express forum - modify as required
            If TDelement.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.Title = "table you want's title" Then
                Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & TDelement.innerText & Chr(34)
                r = r + 1
            End If
    Next

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing  
End Sub
```

I based this off of [this page](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=31831)

Comment: But it will give me the all <TD> values of the whole source page right?

Comment: Yeah. How do you plan on identifying the portion you want to extract? What is unique about it?

Comment: It looks like if your table is defined such that you are looking for the `title` property. you will need to go up 3 levels of `ParentNotes` from `TDelement` and check it's `title` while you are printing. See edits.

Comment: okie.. i will be having a vbs code which will help me to navigate or looping url on the web,once i will reach that particular webpage, i want my vba code to get the <td> values read and insert it to another excel.means using VBS i will jump to the next webpage once the VBA completes its data extraction and save it to an excel.for ex. i am giving the below source code where i want to read the Field name,Operator and values- which are three destination column in my final excel where the vba actually stores its read data:

Comment: You're doing a part of this in VB script and some in VBA? Also I'm not sure this is helping me understand how you're determining which table data you want.

Comment: the table is a nested to a <TD> of a table. and the destination table have no thing in the declaration. it only started as <table> that's it. i was trying to get the full source html her but ccouldn't. here the forum not alloing me to paste the full source code.If i was able to paste it here,hope you can give me the good idea.Any idea how to paste the source Html content here?

Comment: you can edit your question. "Edit" in the bottom left corner of the question post. Post the relevant sample in there.

Comment: "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." error i am getting when try to save the changes..

Comment: Did you try adding the spaces? Or highlight all the code and click the `{ }` button.

Comment: i just updated the html source,hope you can help me now. please check now description content and let me know if it is helpful for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I looked all over for the answer to this question.  I finally found the solution which was actually throuhg recording a macro.  I know, you all think you are above this, but it is actually the best way.  See the full post here: http://automatic-office.com/?p=344
In short, you want to record the macro and go to data --> from web and navigate to your website and select the table you want.
I have used the above solutions "get element by id" type stuff in the past, and it is great for a few elements, but if you want a whole table, and you aren't super experienced, just record a macro.
don't tell your friends and then reformat it to look like your own work so no one knows you used the macro tool ;)

The code looks like this (including all the superfluous setting of default properties to their default values that recording a macro does for you... figure out which are extra and delete them

```
Sub Macro1()
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
 “URL;http://w1.weather.gov/obhistory/KFRI.html”, Destination:=Range(“$D$4″))
 .Name = “KFRI”
 .FieldNames = True
 .RowNumbers = False
 .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
 .PreserveFormatting = True
 .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
 .BackgroundQuery = True
 .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
 .SavePassword = False
 .SaveData = True
 .AdjustColumnWidth = True
 .RefreshPeriod = 0
 .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
 .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
 .WebTables = “4″
 .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
 .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
 .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
 .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
 .WebDisableRedirections = False
 .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
 End Sub
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another way. The tricky thing is if you have a nested table you must 
get parent container whether a div, table. Use F12 developer tools in IE or in Chrome and work your way down. In the example below there is a div which contains a table. In the example given in the question there is a table containing a table so you would have to find that parent table and use code similar to this to get the child table. Hope that helps.

```
     stabledata = ""
     Set oTbl = odiv.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").Item(0)
     Set oThead = odiv.getElementsByTagName("THEAD").Item(0)
     Set oTRows = oThead.getElementsByTagName("TR").Item(0)
     Set oTds = oTRows.getElementsByTagName("TH")

     For Each oTd In oTds
        DoEvents

        stabledata = stabledata & oTd.innertext & Chr(9)

     Next oTd
     stabledata = stabledata & vbCrLf
     Set oTBody = odiv.getElementsByTagName("TBODY").Item(0)
     Set oTRows = oTBody.getElementsByTagName("TR")
     For Each oTRow In oTRows
        DoEvents
        Set oTds = oTRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each oTd In oTds
            DoEvents

            stabledata = stabledata & oTd.innertext & Chr(9)

        Next oTd

        stabledata = stabledata & vbCrLf

     Next oTRow
```