# Unable to extract table from webpage to excel using VBA (which does not have "ID" tag)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a data which is in a form of table in a webpage to my excel file using VBA, actually i am successful in opening and log in and navigate to table area but i am unable to copy the table date in the excel file !! The Reason being it does not have "ID" or "Name" tag assigned to it, It has only "Class" property
Below is the source code of the table from the webpage

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="grid" style="width: 930px;">
```

Also, I cannot use web query as the webpage has user name and password for login

Using online reference i tried few code below are the same i tried !!!

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Link")
Do Until Not IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
Set doc = IE.document

Do While doc.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
IE.document.all("new_username").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("User")
IE.document.all("new_password").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Pass")
IE.document.all("ok").Click
Do While doc.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = "Gateway transactions" Then
link.Click
End If
Next
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_store_id").Item(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("MID")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_from_d").Item(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Fromdate")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_from_m").Item(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Frommon")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_from_y").Item(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Fromyear")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_to_d").Item(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Todate")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_to_m").Item(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Tomon")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_to_y").Item(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("ToYear")
IE.document.getelementsbyname("new_tsrch_type").Item(0).Value = "15"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each tagx In tags
If tagx.Name = "ok" Then
tagx.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Set doc = IE.document 'From here the code starts for extracting table
Set tbl = doc.getelementsbyclassname("grid")
   GetTableData tbl, Sheet1.Range("A1")
End Sub
Sub GetTableData(ByRef tbl, rng As Range)
Dim cl As Object
Dim rw As Object
Dim I As Long
For Each rw In tbl.Rows ' In this line i am getting an error message "Run tine Error 438"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method"
    For Each cl In rw.Cells
        rng.Value = cl.outerText
        Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
    Next cl
    Set rng = rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row + 1, 1)
Next rw
rng.Parent.Cells.WrapText = False
End SuB
```

I hope some one could help me !!! Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi after a intense research, I found the answer, taught of posting it so someone would be benefited !! Actually the real thanks goes to "user2216436" and "Jonny" as they gave me the code in the below link [How to read the nested table <td> values using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159667/how-to-read-the-nested-table-td-values-using-vba) I just edited to match my needs.. I really love this webpage !!!! It is awesome for beginners like me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try copy pasting the table HTML to the sheet:

```
Dim clipboard As Object
Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
clipboard.SetText doc.querySelector("table[class=grid]").outerHTML
clipboard.PutInClipboard
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Also, did you give this a try?